# cannot recover data from or unlock my phone Lenovo Z2 plus

Tags: adb, data-recovery, usb-debugging, lenovo

I needed some data from my old phone `Lenovo Zuk Z2 plus (Z2132)` but I have forgotten the lock screen PIN.

I tried a lot of recovery software, but all of them had a pre-requisite to either have the phone's USB Debugging mode enabled OR the device being rooted AND it's neither of those things.

I tried to enable USB Debugging mode using adb, however it doesn't detect any device when my device is on the lock screen. It detects it as `(no serial number)    unauthorized` only when the device is in recovery mode (that I got to via holding Volume Down & Power button).

I researched and found that if I run the command `adb usb` or some adb command, it would request me to allow USB Debugging via a popup. But the device is only detected when in recovery mode (hence, no popup there).

Is there any way I can access my data OR get my device to be detected when on lockscreen OR enable the usb debugging mode somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods to unlock your device. It depends on you whether you want data from you **internal storage** or you want data from your applications.

1. If you want data from your **internal storage**, you can just download **Aroma File Manager** and flash it from your boot manager in your android device. Aroma **File Manager** let you browse your **Internal Storage** and can let you copy and paste file from your internal storage to external storage like SD card.
2. If you want your android device back to normal state without loosing your device Storage you can simply delete the Gesture.key or pass.key file from your root folder `/data/system/gesture.key` which you can browsed with the help of **Aroma File Manager**.

Conclusion is that you need Aroma File Manager to have access to your android device storage which can help you to get all you data back to you even if you don't know your password.

**MAIN POINT IS THAT THE ABOVE STEP WILL VOID YOUR ANDROID PHONE WARRANTY.**

Comment: You presupposed that OP's device is using a third party custom recovery. OP has not clarified it so it cannot be assumed. And a third party software cannot be installed using a stock recovery.

Comment: Yes, and the device is using the stock recovery. Is there anyway? I have some really important data in it :/

Comment: You can use above method after installing TWRP Recovery on your device.

Comment: @KetanMalhotra Please be warned that you would have to unlock the bootloader to install a custom recovery and unlocking the bootloader would **delete all your userdata**, so the answer posted here is not really useful for your case *at all*.